# UI5 validation of view elements by their attributes

Tags: validation, sapui5

I am new to UI5 and official documentation seems to be too simple so I want to ask 1 thing:

In my Controller I have a fragment/dialog defined using: sap.ui.xmlfragment:

```
this.dialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("some name","xml path",this);
this.dialog.open(); // is called when it should be displayed
```

This dialog contains 1 TextArea and a button OK.  The TextArea looks cca like this:

```
<TextArea rows="5" id="myId" change="onChange" ... />
```

When I click OK, method onSave() (from my controller) is called and I need to access all attributes of the tag  for example like this:

```
onSave: function () {
var rowNum = this.dialog.getElementById("myId").getAttribute("rows");
}
```

Can I do something like this?

Comment: I found following manual where my situation is mentioned, but it does not work for me [code: sap.ui.getCore().byId("txtFirstTitle").setText("Name Surname")] : https://blogs.sap.com/2014/02/20/sapui5-dialogwith-businesscard-as-xml-fragment-along-with-controller/

Comment: So here I found that it is probably impossible to access controls in a fragment: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3649962

Comment: ... But I do not believe it as if I used jQuery I would surely reach the goal

Comment: Damn right, you can access your fragment's components from your controller. I've done it before; if you're stuck on it, write a proper question describing what you've done, showing your code and then I can help.

Comment: @ChrisNeve: I believe my question is clear enough and obvious: "How can I access HTML attributes in a fragment using a controller?" I don't think it is necessary to ask a new question.

Comment: Funny, apart from in your comment I can't see anywhere where it says "How can I access HTML attributes in a fragment using a controller?". What I see is "Can I do something like this?". Interesting how we see different things while reading the same question.

Comment: But the question is all about accessing HTML attributes in controller :-o ... because of validation